# Concerning details of the proof of Hartshorne II 8.15

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

[image]

Here are the statement and proof Hartshorne II 8.15. I got the following questions concerning the proof:

1. Concerning *non-singularity* of abstract variety, it is required to prove the iff relation for **every point** of $X$, why the consideration only at the closed points can be generalized?
2. I cannot see how (8.14A) can be applied explicitly.

Below are the statements of (8.14A) and (Ex. 5.7):
[image]

[image]

They are likely to be trivial questions for most of you, but it will help a lot for me to understand the context. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Now I have a intuitive feeling for that. Because for any prime ideal contained in the maximal ideal corresponds to the closed point, the second localization by the prime ideal contained should also be regular local ring, and this will prove for any point in $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is a non-closed point, then there is a closed point $y$ in its closure, and then $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is just the localization of $\mathcal{O}_{X,y}$ at the prime ideal corresponding to $x$ (proof: we can restrict to an affine open set containing $x$, and then this is just the fact that if $A$ is a ring and $P\subseteq Q$ are prime ideals, then $(A_Q)_P\cong A_P$).  So, if we know that $\mathcal{O}_{X,y}$ is regular for all closed points $y$, that implies $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is regular for all points $x$.

Comment: Thanks for your verification, that is exactly what I thought!!